# MySQL Workbench doesn't "see" updates from JDBC Java program

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I have this code

```
    public PreparedStatement InsertDepartmentQuery() {
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO department (DepartmentNo,DepartmentName,DepartmentLocation) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return ps;
}
```

and

```
public void InsertyTuple() {
    
    int a  = -1;
    ps = InsertDepartmentQuery();
       
    try {
    ps.setInt(1, DeptNo);
    ps.setString(2, DeptName);
    ps.setString(3, DeptLocation);
    a = ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

and

```
      Department test = new Department(106, "TB_1", "Tabuk");
  
  test.InsertyTuple();
```

It executes fine in Eclipse, even a select query in there returns the expected results. But none of the inserts are showing up in MySQL Workbench. I tried restarting the connection and it didn't work. Autocommits are on as when I tried to do a manual commit it told me so.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same database in both situations?

Comment: Do you use autocommit or where is the transaction commited?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I even deleted other schemas and DBs from MySQL to see if that was the problem.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli autocommits are on by default. I even tried to do a commit just to see and was met with "java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Wrong schema name

Well I found the problem so I'll just leave the answer and feel stupid later.

I had the connection started as

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL", username, password);
```

when it should've been

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL", username, password);
```

the "project" replacing "mysql" is the name of my schema in MySQL.